# How do I solve this. I am trying allow user input to solve this problem that multiplies weight x a changing variable

Tags: python-3.x

[Help me solve this, what do I set new_weight = to. ][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkEdl.jpgprint("I have information for the following planets:\n")
print("I have information for the following planets:\n")

```
print("   1. Venus   2. Mars    3. Jupiter")
print("   4. Saturn  5. Uranus  6. Neptune\n")

weight = 185
venus = 1
mars = 2
jupiter = 3
saturn = 4
uranus = 5
neptrune = 6

venus_rg = 0.91
mars_rg = 0.38
jupiter_rg = 2.34
saturn_rg = 1.06
uranus_rg = 0.92
neptune_rg = 1.19
inp=input
# Write an if statement below:
inp = input("Enter Planet Number:")

if  inp == 1:
  weight= weight * 0.91
elif inp == 2:
  weight= weight * 0.38
elif inp == 3:
  weight = weight * 2.34
elif inp == 4:
  weight= weight * 1.06
elif inp == 5:
  weight = weight * 0.92
elif inp == 6:
  weight = weight * 1.19

print(weight)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please post your code as text and not as an image.  What happens if you run your code as is?

Comment: I am trying to ask the user for input. once the user enters a planet number I would like the program to calculate the weight of the user based on the planet. When I run the code it will only print out the set weight of 185. I do not know what to set a New_weight variable to properly calculate this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```py
inp = input("Enter Planet Number:")
```

inp is a string. So say they enter 1, it becomes `'1'`.
You need to call `int` around it to cast it to an integer.
So:

```py
inp = int(input("Enter Planet Number:"))
```